# Finding tables without primery keys, and non null unique keys

Tags: oracle-11g

I have a requirement to find out tables without primary key or Not-NULL unique constraints. How do I do that in Oracle ?

I also want to find out any primary key column which has datatype as TIMESTAMP

Thanks for your help in adavance

Comment: Can you program?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/concepts/data_dictionary.htm